# Automatically join missing data gaps in Highcharts JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts, missing-data

I'm currently looking to implement [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/) into my application, using months as the x-axis categories.

However, I have gaps in my data, and wish for the chart to automatically connect the gaps.

For example, if I don't have any data for March, I want February and April to connect with a linear line.

Using the highcharts demo, I have edited the data to demonstrate what currently happens by default:

http://jsfiddle.net/kf26t/1/

```
data: [7.0, 10.0, null, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

As you can see, there is a break in the line between February and April.

I've considered removing the months with no data from the categories, but then this will give a skewed result as February and April will be an equal distance away from each other as April and May, which won't give an accurate representation.

If I am to remove 4 months, this inaccurate representation is exaggerated:

http://jsfiddle.net/kf26t/2/

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

The only solution I can think of is to calculate the average between the months, but I don't wish to display averages.

Is there any built-in way of filling in these gaps in Highchart JS? If not, is there a neater solution to what I have suggested?

---

Alternatively, is there a way of seperating the x-axis based on value? So if there is no March month, February and April appear the distance of 2 months away.

This would also be useful when integers are the x-axis. For example if I had "1, 2, 10", I wouldn't want these to be evenly spread.

Comment: What is wrong with the average thing? Surely that would be the vlaue that Highcharts would auto display if it filled in the gaps. I guess perhaps you want it without a hover point then?

Comment: @musefan That's correct, its an average generated, not inputted data. Therefore I don't want it to be a "milestone".

Comment: @musefan See my latest edit. I'd rather not display March as a category at all and just spread the categories further apart.

Comment: I don't think the inaccurate representation is inaccurate at all... I don't understand what a better graph would look like :s

Comment: @amhed Lets say this was fuel price over years, and you've got data for 1970, 1971 and 2013. If they are all equally spread, the degrees at which the line is displayed between 1970 and 1971 would not be comparable to 1971 - 2013.

Comment: I'm confused as to what are you are asking, you want a space for "missing" months and to connect lines over nulls?  http://jsfiddle.net/kf26t/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of behaviour [**Highstocks JS**](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) should be used instead of Highcharts JS.

```
data: [
       [Date.UTC(2013,  0, 1), 1],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1), 2 ],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 3,  1), 4],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 4,  1), 5 ],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1), 6 ],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 1), 7],
       [Date.UTC(2013,  7,  1), 8],
       [Date.UTC(2013,  8,  1),9],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 1), 10],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 10, 1), 11],
       [Date.UTC(2013, 11, 1), 12]
      ]
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/*

Comment: what advantage does highstock have over highcharts here?

Answer (score 12):

I may be missing something, but by your example and explanation, you seem to be looking for the connectNulls property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls

Comment: is there any options for irregular date time series?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - can you be more specific?