# Highcharts skip non-provided steps in a series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have bar chart in high chart. I send it items for x & y. It happened that x-values are numerics. In such case, it assumes that there are missing entries and add the missing entries. I want to force high chart not to include those assumed items. Is that possible without using categories?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/96bk4661/1/
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        "chart": {
            "type": "column"
        },
        "series": [{
            "name": "X-Axis",
            "data": [
                [1, 77926],
                [2, 71245],
                [4, 75275],
                [5, 78175],
                [6, 75369],
                [7, 78145],
                [8, 77638],
                [9, 75706],
                [12, 77491]
            ],
            "color": "#1AA4D5"
        }]
    });
});
```

This one is different from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973457/automatically-join-missing-data-gaps-in-highcharts-js`
I don't want the values to be included on the x-axis.

Comment: You could alter the labels on the axis, but not sure that is any better than using categories.

Comment: Why not just have your data as a series of y points? Is the x value important - do you care that x=1 has a y=77926 or do you just want to know that 77926 is the first point?

Comment: Yes it matters. Because x and y are dynamic and I do display that to the user in a tooltip.

Comment: Wouldnt the absence of a value matter? Why not show the missing element?

Comment: @wergeld, this is based on dynamic data. Sometimes there is a big gap that makes the chart messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's no other way and I am using categories. Thanks @Ondkloss !

Answer (score 0):

Use highstock and then set ordinal parameter as true.

```
xAxis:{
        ordinal:true
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/96bk4661/2/

Comment: This is not a solution. Please open your jsfiddle and maximize the view, you will notice that the values are there on the x-Axis.

Comment: In addition, this will require an additional license.